# Null referency for child using @OneToOne annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I am getting a null reference on a child object.

Let me explain:

I have two classes:

```
@Entity
@Table (name="CONTROLADORES")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Controlador.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Controlador c"), 
    @NamedQuery(name="Controlador.findByIdWithChilds", query="SELECT c FROM Controlador c JOIN FETCH c.cruce WHERE c.id = :id")
})
public class Controlador implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1018356240274259744L;

    @Expose
    private long id;

    @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @GenericGenerator(name="increment", strategy = "increment")
        @Column(name="controlador_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn  
    public CruceSemaforos getCruce() {
        return cruce;
    }

    public void setCruce(CruceSemaforos cruces) {
        this.cruce = cruce;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table (name="CRUCE_SEMAFOROS")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="CruceSemaforos.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM CruceSemaforos c")
})
public class CruceSemaforos implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 140756341984196420L;

    @Expose
    private long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="cruce_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Controlador controlador;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CONTROLADORES_idControlador", referencedColumnName = "controlador_id")
    public Controlador getControlador() {
        return controlador;
    }

    public void setControlador(Controlador controlador) {
        this.controlador = controlador;
    }
}
```

I can create and presist instances of this objects and in the database, the foreing key i set with the correct value (i mean: if i have a ***Controlador***
which has a ***Cruce*** in the table CRUCE_SEMAFOROS the controlador id is setted in the column ***CONTROLADORS_idControlador***.

This part works fine.

The problem is that when i try to get the ***Controlador***, the ***cruce*** attibute of this class is null!

I think thats maybe an annotation error (i am new in the world of annotation for hibernate).

Please i would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: How do you get Controlador? Do you call the namedQuery 'findByIdWithChilds' ?

Comment: '@JoinColumn' in class Controlador looks suspicious. Remove this annotation. You need to add a 'mappedBy = "CruceSemaforos"' then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every bi-directional association, you must choose one and only one owner side. In your case, the `CruceSemaforos.controlador` is the owner of this association.

So you need to declare the other side as `inverse`, by using the `mappedBy` directive:

```
public class Controlador implements Serializable {

    ...

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "controlador") 
    public CruceSemaforos getCruce() {
        return cruce;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is most likely correct. If you go look into your current database schema, you will probably find a foreign key column in *both* tables, which means you're storing redundant information that can introduce inconsistencies. Your JPA implementation cannot assume that there is a bidirectional relationship between both entities, unless you tell it so.

Comment: Exactly, a bidirectional association needs only one FK.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, i tried this, but the error persists. In CruceSemaforos what annotation should be?

Comment: @VladMihalcea Thanks you very much, i finnaly found what the problem was. In the setter of the attribute cruce, the parameter as input is called cruces, so the setter doesnt works as espected. This plus the annotations errors were the problem.